# Javascript Asynchronous Events emitting mechanism

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, dom-events, eventemitter

I'm trying to run this code in node REPl

```
var E = require('events').EventEmitter;
var e = new E(); //controller

e.on('msg', function(){ console.log(1) }); //handling

(function(){

  console.log(0);
  e.emit('msg');
  console.log(2);

}()); //self-execution
```

so it gives in console

```
0
1
2
```

does it mean that event emitting is synchronous
and that code is some-way equal to:

```
(function(){

  console.log(0);
  console.log(1);
  console.log(2);

}()); //self-execution
```

Comment: Yes, events are dispatched synchronously in node EventEmitter. (but don't have to, it's a good idea not rely on order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emitter is synchronous indeed.

But pay attention, if you are going to code asynchronous statements in your listener it will affect your code.